# Highlight every first row element in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, row, highlight

I have a row of elements (defined name as 'myhazards') I'm converting to a column of elements, eg:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
```

This is my formula for converting the rows to columns:

```
=INDEX(allhazards,1+INT((ROW($A1)-1)/COLUMNS(allhazards)),MOD(ROW($A1)-1+COLUMNS(allhazards),COLUMNS(allhazards))+1)
```

However, I would like to modify my formula to highlight the 1st row element to yellow

```
1  <-- highlight cell yellow
2
3
4
5  <-- highlight cell yellow
6
7
8
```

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

you cannot apply format in a formula for contents

you need to use *conditional formatting* instead

1. Select all the cells of your sheet
2. Click *Conditional formatting* | *New Rule*

   [image]
3. In the *New Formatting Rule* dialog, click *Use a formula to determine cells to format*
4. in the *Format values where this formula is true:* field,
   enter this formula

   ```
    =MOD(ROW(),4)=1
   ```

   that selects every fourth row (row numbers modulo 4) starting at 1 (those that their modulo is equal 1).
5. Click *Format...* button and select your desired Fill format

   [image: New Formatting Rule]
6. Click *OK* button and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Further to what @PA suggeted, if all the values in allhazards are unique you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(YourTestedCell,allhazards,1,0)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

And you won't get the column witdh of allhazards to be hardcoded.